# animating object with glfw

Tags: opengl, glfw

I'm trying to animate a circle across the window which has the default coordinates -1.0 < x < 1.0 and -1.0 < y < 1.0.  I generate a random position for the circle and a random angle at which it moves across the window.

```
GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "model");
GLfloat timer = glfwGetTime();
timer /= 10;

glm::mat4 model;
glm::vec3 position = circle.get_position();
GLfloat angle = glm::radians(circle.get_angle());

position.x += timer*cos(angle);
position.y += timer*sin(angle);   

model = glm::translate(model, position);
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, NUM_CIRCLE_VERTICES);
```

Now the object animates from its initial position to off the screen.  I would like it to appear on the other side of the window when it reaches the edge (i.e. turn x into -x).  I was thinking that the sine function would be useful here but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

much simpler than using trig:

```
if(position.x < -1)
    position.x+=2;
if(position.y < -1)
    position.y+=2;
if(position.x > 1)
    position.x-=2;
if(position.y > 1)
    position.y-=2;
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Let's say original position is x = 0.0.  With timer increasing in the positive direction.  Once x == 1.0 then x will become -1.0.  But timer is increasing so next iteration x = 1.1 (let's say) and then x will be -1.1 and so on.

Comment: if x is 1.1 then it will become -0.9

Comment: This solution does not provide movement continuity of circle. Right after center of circle pass the bound, circle will appear at the opposite side. What you can do is duplicating your circle. Using ratchet freak's solution when center pass the bound, let one of circle keep moving and let the other circle appear from opposite side.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a smoother animation, you must not use an absolute value of timer, but a difference between the last value and the current, called delta.

So, I suggest you to change your code to accomplish this:

```
static GLfloast last = 0;
GLfloat delta;
GLfloat timer = glfwGetTime();
delta = timer - last;
last = timer;

...
position.x += delta*cos(angle);
position.y += delta*sin(angle);   

// using ratchet freak's solution
if(position.x < -1)
    position.x+=2;
if(position.y < -1)
    position.y+=2;
if(position.x > 1)
    position.x-=2;
if(position.y > 1)
    position.y-=2;
```